# In Python: how to write a sparse matrix to a csv file?

Tags: python, excel, csv, matrix, matplotlib

I am a newbie to Python. I have been given a script which generates random numbers and puts them in a 126x81 sparse matrix. I would like to generate a csv file with: **Cell_ID**; **Cell_X**; **Cell_Y**; **Val**. Cell X and Y are of course the coordinates for each cell. The script I have has a loop which generates an "outputs.csv" file, but in it data are not displayed the way I want them (there are square brackets at the beginning/end of each line and there are ellipsis [...] in place of some values). To sum up, I am not able to read the whole content of the matrix.

If I could, I would upload a picture to show you how I would like these data to look like when read in Notepad or Excel, but I am not allowed to do so. However, these data should look like a typical csv file with each value aligned under its column. 
Thank you for your help guys! :)

Comment: You should include more of your code.  For example, what is `g`?  Also, it looks like your variables `m` and `n` are out of scope when you write to the file.

Comment: `g` is my matrix. The `m` and `n` values do not correspond to the `140` and `100` you see in the first line - I have been told this script uses a reduced window to assign and plot values.

Comment: Please define `g`. At least tell us what type it has. Maybe your problem can be solved by fixing this line: `val = g[m:n]` to `val = g[m, n]` (but that is a wild guess). And the following line `outputFile.write(...` obviously has the wrong indentation.

Comment: `g = gauss_kern(n, sizey=ny)`. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: No, since I don't know what `gauss_kern` is, that does not help at all. I am guessing that `g` is a `numpy.ndarray`. If so what I suggested above should fix the issue.

Comment: `g` is also defined like this: `g = np.exp(-(x**2/float(size)+y**2/float(sizey)))`.

Comment: @hitzg: by replacing `val=g[m:n]` with `val=g[m,n]` I get this: `---> 59         val = g[m,n]
     60         outputFile.write(str(n) + "," + str(m) + "," + str(val) +"\n")
     61 outputFile.close()
IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 100

Comment: Well that means that `range(126)` goes up to high. Use `range(140)` and `range(100)`. (Assuming that this is the size of your matrix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the standard library supports csv, let's use it:

```
import numpy
import csv

N = 126
M = 81

g = numpy.random.rand(N, M)

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['x', 'y', 'value'])
    for (n, m), val in numpy.ndenumerate(g):
        writer.writerow([n, m, val])
```

Comment: Thank, although adding these lines produces a csv file which, when opened with Notepad, reveals to have stopped at N=139. How can I make it stop at N=125? (if N starts from 0 that is of course 126 columns).

Comment: Do you mean in your code or mine? I recommend checking g's shape before writing. The enumeration us unlikely to be wrong.